# CPU profiling under Phantom.js

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling, phantomjs

I'd like to profile a javascript application under phantomjs.  The `console` API has a `profile` and a `profileEnd` function, but calling them seems to have no effect.  The source code of the [console object](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/page/Console.cpp) shows that some instrumentation should take place, but I don't know how to enable it.  The [official documentation](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki) doesn't mention profiling, either.  [A reference on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/f34gP6KXhaE) suggests it was not available in 2012.  There is a [related but broader issue](https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=232) too.

To make a long story short: is it possible to use `console.profile` under phantomjs?  If so, please give me an example of how.

Comment: Some functions behave differently depending on whether they are called inside or outside of a `page.evaluate()` call. Perhaps some of the `console` functionality you are looking for is only available without `page.evaluate( function() { ... } )`?